# Using span to zoom to user location

Tags: iphone, ios, zooming, cllocationmanager, html

Here's my code right now.  I'm getting callbacks from Location manager, but it doesn't want to zoom to the location.

```
#import "MapViewController.h"


@interface MapViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;


@end

@implementation MapViewController

@synthesize mapView = _mapView;
@synthesize mPlacemark = _mPlacemark;
@synthesize location = _location;
@synthesize mStoreLocationButton = _mStoreLocationButton;
@synthesize locationManager = _locationManager;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
 }

- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];
mapView=[[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
//mapView.showsUserLocation=TRUE;
mapView.delegate=self;
[self.view insertSubview:mapView atIndex:0];

NSLog(@"locationServicesEnabled: %@", [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] ? @"YES":@"NO");
if ([self locationManager] == nil) {
    CLLocationManager *newLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [newLocationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    [newLocationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
    [self setLocationManager:newLocationManager];
}

[[self locationManager] setDelegate:self];
[[self locationManager] startUpdatingLocation];
NSLog(@"Started updating Location");

}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

NSLog(@"Did update to location");
mStoreLocationButton.hidden=FALSE;
location=newLocation.coordinate;

MKCoordinateRegion region;
region.center=location;
MKCoordinateSpan span;
span.latitudeDelta=0.01;
span.longitudeDelta=0.01;
region.span=span;


[mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];


 }
```

I can post header file if need be.  Mainly I'm just concerned with zooming.  I just don't understand why it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code for `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation` seems right.

Try changing the line

```
[self.view insertSubview:mapView atIndex:0];
```

to:

```
[self.view addSubview:mapView];
```

It might be that the `MKMapView` isn't redrawing itself because of how it's displayed in your view.

Comment: Now I noticed another problem.  Changing that line now hides a uibutton I had on the map.  Do I need to add another subview on top of the mapview?

Comment: Sorry, got it figured out.  Thanks again for your response.